# Оптимизация html, выданого с помощью php уже после его "выдачи"

Tags: php, оптимизация

Есть `php`-страница, условное содержимое:

```
asd
<ul>
   <?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){ ?>
      <li>
         <?php echo $i; ?>
      </li>
   <?php } ?>
</ul>
asd
```

Результат, который получаем:

```
asd
<ul>

      <li>
         0
      </li>

      <li>
         1
      </li>

      <li>
         2
      </li>

</ul>
asd
```

Результат, который хочется получать:

```
asd<ul><li>0</li><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>asd
```

Как это сделать, минимально влияя на существующий `php` код? Тоесть в идеале -- выполнение одной функции перед/после всего кода, как такое лучше осуществить?

Comment: хммм... а в чем отличия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код, написанный ниже, выведет вот это:

**результат в виде html:**

```
asd<ul> <li> 0 </li> <li> 1 </li> <li> 2 </li> </ul>asd
```

**Сам код:**

```
<?php
/* Один раз объявляем функцию, где это удобно. */
function sanitize_output($buffer) {

    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // вырезаем после тегов все отступы, кроме пробелов
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // вырезаем перед тегами все отступы, кроме пробелов
        '/(\s)+/s'       // заменяем несколько пробелов одним
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

/* Единожды вызываем ее перед выводом контента */
ob_start("sanitize_output");

?>

asd
<ul>
   <?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){ ?>
      <li>
         <?php echo $i; ?>
      </li>
   <?php } ?>
</ul>
asd
```

**Есть один минус:** в некоторых случаях могут вырезаться переносы строк внутри тега **pre**

Comment: Как я понимаю, если поднастроить регулярные выражения, можно добиться идеального и правильного результата.

Спасибо, именно то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно например работать с буфером. Почитайте об этом: http://www.php.su/functions/?ob_start

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
<?php
$str='acd<ul>';
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
  {
     $str=$str.'<li>'.$i.'</li>';
  }
$str=$str.'</ul>asd';
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Это неудобно. Идея я в оптимизации уже "выданного", а не в ущемлении удобности вывода.

Answer (score 0):

Я с помощью yui compressor оптимизирую и сжимаю js, css, что то подобное можно cделать и с php файликами(написать регулярное выражение, которое удалит все переносы строк и ненужные пробелы). С помощью phing автоматизирую процесс сборки и развертывание на сервере.